# Fullstop after \dots in a formula

Tags: equations, punctuation, english

Should I put fullstop after `\dots` in a formula in the end of a sequence?

Consider for example the nonsense formula

```
$$E=mc^2 + \dots .$$
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  How do you know he is using LaTeX? ;)

Comment: @User: Fair point ;-)

Comment: The typographic rules states that ellipsis (since `\dots` gives “…”) shall not be followed by a period. Hence, the answer is no.

Comment: @Zoxume  But they are math ellipsis, so a symbol, and not text ellipsis, therefore they are not a punctuation mark

Comment: You should load `amsmath` and input your formula as `\[E=mc^2+\dotsb.\]` If you aren't using LaTeX, but plain TeX, use `\cdots`.

Comment: I would follow them with a dot if they were centered dots as in this case, and probably not follow them with a dot if they were low dots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### LaTeX answer

Never ever use `$$` in LaTeX; see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Of course, loading `amsmath` is recommended, so the equation can be typed in as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
E=mc^2+\dots+\frac{GmM}{r^2}+\dotsb.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note that you have to help LaTeX and tell it what kind of dots you need: “dots for **b**inary operation” in this case.

### Plain TeX answer

```
$$
E=mc^2+\cdots+{GmM\over r^2}+\cdots.
$$

\bye
```

### AMS-TeX answer

```
\input amstex
\documentstyle{amsppt}

\document

$$
E=mc^2+\dots+\frac{GmM}{r^2}+\dotsb.
$$

\enddocument
```

### Output

The output is essentially the same in all three cases.

[image]

Comment: From a Physicist's point of view I should downvote this **wrong** equation ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm a mathematician, I work with dimensionless units. `;-)`

Comment: But the 'solution' of the ODE would be wrong anyway, in any units